# What request should I make to /oauth/token, OAuth2 sample to use password grant?

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

running `sparklr2` and `tonr2` without problem (code authorization grant), out of the box, without any modification.
Want to try password grant. tried `GET` and `POST` with parameters
`?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=marissa&password=koala`

If I understand correctly, `.withClient("my-trusted-client").authorizedGrantTypes("password",...)` means this setup support password grant, right?

both `GET`, `POST` return with `http 401, blocked by AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(), SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() return null`.

so, does this mean, even with `username` & `password` parameters, I still have to put authentication (in base64) inside header? or something else I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out after tracing spring `oauth2` source code.
even with `username` & `password` in `POST` body, the token endpoint still need authentication to be accessible.

and for password grant, the authentication in http header is not `username` & `password` (sparklr2 user), but have to use `client_id` and `client_secret` instead. encode `"client_id:secret"` with base64, put it in request header, token endpoint is now accessible.